# Disable Update in Java 7.13+

Tags: group-policy, java, update

My users cannot install their own software.
I'm using GPO and an .mst to customize and deploy Java 7 with the following options under Properties:

```
  AUTOUPDATECHECK = 0
  EULA = 1
  IEXPLORER = 1
  JAVAUPDATE = 0
  JU = 0
  REBOOTYESNO = NO
  WEB_JAVA_SECURITY_LEVEL = M
```

However, Oracle recently deployed Java 7.15 and all of my users suddenly get redirected to java.com and everybody is down. They can't use the application because Java insists on taking them to java.com for an update and they can't do the update themselves.

How can I completely prevent Java from checking for updates?

Answer (score 4):

You should set the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Update\Policy\EnableJavaUpdate` registry key value to `0` on your users' machines to prevent updates. Apparently the installer has not done that despite your best efforts. After installation, you simply should use the "Registry" section in a group policy object to distribute the setting among your domain's machines.

Walkthrough:

http://gpyall.com/archives/how-do-i-disable-java-updates-with-group-policy/